# Android Draw9patch is missing?

Tags: android

Can anyone please explain why the draw9patch isn't on my computer despite ADT and all? A search after the jar-file doesn't give any result.

I believed it should be installed by default. AFAIK, nobody else has had this problem.

Can anyone help? I've tried making 9 patches on my own using Paint.NET by adding one black pixel to the left and top of the image, but as I am new to Android, I can't make it work. I even tried a utility called better9patch to no avail. I am getting quite frustrated right now as I think the graphics of a program should be the least of your concern when programming.

Comment: So you dont have `draw9path.bat` under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools`? more generally android-sdk\tools\ folder where your sdk is installed

Comment: EXACTLY! It should be there, but it isn't. The only things I have in that folder are adb.exe, AdbWinApi.dll,AdbWinUsbApi.dll Also, my path looks like this: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools   I do not have 'tools' only.

Answer (score 13):

Infact, the popular `draw9patch` application is now available as a feature in the android studio application itself. If you try to open any files with a `.9.png` extension in your project, it will be opened in a 9 patch drawer perspective. Here is a screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 5):

You should download "draw9patch" folowing this link: https://androidstudio.io/downloads/tools/download-the-latest-version-of-draw9patch.jar.html.

Afterwards you extract the file and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Android Asset Studio
Simple nine-patch generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html). This is web application.

> A collection of tools to easily generate assets such as launcher icons
> for your Android app.

Project page: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Answer (score 1):

open up your terminal navigate to sdk/tools. and type

```
chmod +x draw9patch
```

`./draw9patch`

hope it can fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The program should be under `android-sdk/tools/draw9patch`. If you want to create the image manually, you need 1px-wide transparent border all around the image with black dots on those empty spaces to denote patches

Comment: Hi, Srdjan! I tried a manual image. It doesn't seem to work. I have an XML-file (background.xml) which creates a background that fades from blue to black. But, I also want an image (testred.9.png) above background. The image does not go all the way to the left and right border.

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@layout/background"    
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/white_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/testred" />

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. I don't know why it became like this.

Comment: New code should be always added to Question, you can edit your question and add more information (code etc). Comments not allow for formatting