# draw9patch does not open image files anymore

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3, android-sdk-tools

I can not open any PNG files anymore with draw9patch. When i use the menu (File - Open 9-patch), just nothing happens. No file browser opens. When i drag a PNG into the app UI, it freezes right away and i have to kill the process. I'm using the Android SDK Tools 22.0.5, which is the latest version, on a Mac.

I've tried it with `android-sdk/tools/draw9patch` and `java -jar android-sdk/tools/lib/draw9patch.jar`. Both with the same result and no log output or anything.

Any ideas what's going wrong here?

**Edit:**

Just downloaded the whole ADT bundle again. Still no change.

Comment: Take a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/23150433/519814

Answer (score 0):

Of course, one more time: just after i ask on SO, i figure it out.

I tried to open draw9patch directly. Seems it does not like that. When i open it from within eclipse (right click on the PNG - open with - other - internal editors - Android 9-patch editor), then it works just fine.